# Delegate keeps returning nil

Tags: swift

in my view controller, i have set up like this.

```
protocol MenuDelegate {
func updateIndexOfMenuExpanded(index: Bool)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
var delegate : MenuDelegate?

func performaction() -> Void{
    delegate!.updateIndexOfMenuExpanded(false)
}
}
```

and in my baseviewcontroller

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController, MenuDelegate{

func updateIndexOfMenuExpanded(index: Bool){
    self.menuIsExpanded = index
}
}
```

please help. thank you.

Comment: Because it is nil. You are not setting it anywhere.

Comment: i am new in programming, how to set it and where to set it?

Comment: [Delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID276)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the delegate first.

```
let viewController = ViewController()
let baseViewController = BaseViewController()
viewController.delegate = baseViewController
```

It would also be wise to make the delegate a weak reference and to not force unwrap with `!`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    weak var delegate : MenuDelegate?
    func performaction() {
        delegate?.updateIndexOfMenuExpanded(false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegate is used when you want to pass data between viewcontrollers.this aproach is one to one

Here is the answer how to pass data using delegate
in viewcontroller

define protocol in view controller

```
protocol ViewController1BackClicked {  
func btnBackClicked(str : String)
```

}

class ViewController1: UIViewController {

```
var strTitle : String?
var delegate : ViewController1BackClicked?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if strTitle != nil{
        title = strTitle
    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {

    delegate?.btnBackClicked("Krutarth")


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

now Protocol is created.to pass data in another view controller

viewcontroller 1 we want to access data

```
    func btnBackClicked(str: String) {
    title = str
}
```

output : Krutarth

this is example how to use protocol